# Windows Form with String Table

Tags: c#, user-interface, localization, string-table

I have Normal Windows Form (WinForm) C# (.Net 3.5) application, this application has label with text and menus and etc...
also this application display sometimes Message Boxes to the user, and write some information to files.

I would like that all information that the user can see (by GUI or by files) will be manage by (One, if it possible) String Table. My problem is that I can't find how to move all of my GUI controllers texts to a string table in the resources file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For forms and other GUIO components, set their Localizable property to true. This will automatically move texts to resource files.

For sting literals in your code, the [resource refactoring tool](http://www.codeplex.com/ResourceRefactoring) is your friend

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the Text property of the labels to either an application setting or string resource in the Forms Designer's properties window.